# Fusion rules for the Lie algebra $\frak{so}_{2n+1}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}_{2n+1}$ where can I find a description of the fusion rules of it fundamental representations? In more detail: For $\pi_i$ and $\pi_j$ two fundamental weights of $\mathfrak{so}_{2n+1}$, $V_{\pi_i}$ and $V_{\pi_j}$ the corresponding irreducible representations, where can I find an explicit formula for determining the fundamental representations appearing on the RHS of the identity
$$
V_{\pi_i} \otimes V_{\pi_j} \simeq V_{\pi_{i_1}} \oplus \dotsb \oplus V_{\pi_{i_m}}.
$$
For the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ there is a well-known approach using Young diagrams. I would like to see such an approach for the case of $\mathfrak{so}_{2n+1}$.

Comment: There are various notions of "orthogonal tableaux" but they are all quite complicated (symplectic is usually easier). But "Littelmann paths" (see "A generalization of the Littlewood-Richardson rule" by Peter Littelmann, https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(90)90086-4) works to give a tensor product decomposition rule in all types.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littelmann_path_model which compares the path model to other approaches like crystals and standard monomials.

Comment: If you need to calculate specific examples you can also use the program LiE (http://wwwmathlabo.univ-poitiers.fr/~maavl/LiE/). It normally has a web interface but that seems to be down at the moment.

Comment: Kwon has an explicit combinatorial rule, but I can answer properly only tomorrow.